# Paths /ASP.NET/Https and /Microsoft/UserSecrets) not shared on mac

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

Getting below error using docker-compose up on macOS -

/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(5,5): Error: The APPDATA variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Removing dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1
Removing dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1
Building xyz
Building xyz
Recreating 886c8806b528_dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1 ... 
Recreating 57afcf6f0cb0_dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1  ... 
Recreating 886c8806b528_dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1 ... error
ERROR: for 886c8806b528_dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1  Cannot start service xyz: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe paths /Microsoft/UserSecrets and /ASP.NET/Https\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
Recreating 57afcf6f0cb0_dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1  ... error
ERROR: for 57afcf6f0cb0_dockercompose9508177338158005990_xyz_1  Cannot start service xyz: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe paths /Microsoft/UserSecrets and /ASP.NET/Https\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
ERROR: for xyz  Cannot start service xyz: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe paths /Microsoft/UserSecrets and /ASP.NET/Https\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
ERROR: for xyz  Cannot start service xyz: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe paths /Microsoft/UserSecrets and /ASP.NET/Https\r\nare not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.\r\n.'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project..

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting (docker-compose)

Answer (score 29):

This issue happens when you open, in Visual Studio for Mac, a project that was created using Visual Studio for Windows. Since most developers on my team are using Windows computers, I wanted to find a solution that would allow me to run the project without modifying its configuration. It required a lot of time and research, but I finally made it work:

1. Check if the folder `~/.aspnet/https` exists. If it does, skip to **step 5**.
2. Create the folder structure `~./asp.net/https`.
3. Run the command below to install the development certificates that allow you to access `localhost` through HTTPS. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos).

   ```bsh
   dotnet dev-certs https --trust
   ```
4. Run the command below to export the development certificate. Take note of the password as you will need it later:

   ```bsh
   dotnet dev-certs https -ep ${HOME}/.aspnet/https/FILE_NAME.pfx -p PASSWORD
   ```
5. Check if the folder `~/.microsoft/usersecrets` exists. If it does, it means you already have some User Secrets defined, so you can probably skip to **step 7**, otherwise, continue below.
6. Get the User Secrets ID for the Assembly of the Web Application you're building. It is usually located in a file named like `Your.Project.Package.Name.Assembly.cs`. You can also search for `UserSecrets.UserSecretsIdAttribute("` in your project folder and take the GUID.

   > You might need to repeat this step for multiple assemblies in your solution if you're using Docker Compose to deploy more than one Web application at the same time.
7. Inside `~./microsoft/usersecrets`, create a folder with the GUID you got on step 6, assuming one does not exist already. If it does, you can simply update the file `secrets.json` inside it with the contents of the next step.
8. Create the file `secrets.json` and insert the following:

   ```
   {
     "Kestrel": {
       "Certificates": {
         "Default": {
           "Path": "/root/.aspnet/https/<FILE_NAME from Step 4>.pfx",
           "Password": "<PASSWORD from Step 4>"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
9. Create a file named `.env` in the same folder where your Docker Compose configuration files are located inside the solution with the following content:

   ```
   APPDATA=/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME
   ```

   This file will be picked up by Docker Compose automatically when Visual Studio runs the tool.
10. Add the file `.env` you just created to `.gitignore`, so it doesn't get committed with your changes by mistake. This will ensure other developers with different environments can use this approach as well.
11. Create a symbolic link to point `~/ASP.NET` to `.aspnet` as follows:

    ```
    ln -s ~/.aspnet ~/ASP.NET
    ```
12. Create a symbolic link to point `~/ASP.NET/Https` to `~/.aspnet/https` as follows:

    ```
    ln -s ~/.aspnet/https ~/ASP.NET/Https
    ```
13. Create a symbolic link to point `~/Microsoft` to `~/.microsoft` as follows:

    ```
    ln -s ~/.microsoft ~/Microsoft
    ```
14. Create a symbolic link to point ~/Microsoft/UserSecrets`to`~/.microsoft/usersecrets` as follows:

    ```
    ln -s ~/.microsoft/usersecrets ~/Microsoft/UserSecrets
    ```

If you follow all steps correctly, Docker Compose will be able to resolve the Windows path in your Mac environment, find the required certificate password and run the solution correctly.

The outcome is that you only need to commit your `.gitignore` changes to make sure your `.env` file doesn't get included in the repo by mistake affecting others unintentionally - no further changes are required to the project.

**Edit on August 4th, 2019:** Some symlink creation parameters were in reverse order. Huge thanks to [@BRBdot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151266/brbdot) for pointing it out.

References:

1. [Hosting ASP.NET Core Images with Docker over HTTPS](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/aspnetcore-docker-https.md)
2. [Developing locally with ASP.NET Core under HTTPS, SSL, and Self-Signed Certs](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx)
3. [How to setup the dev certificate when using Docker in development](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6199)

Comment: @Leonardo you might wanna check your symbolic links again. Other than that everything works as described. Thanks for putting together this document!

Comment: @BRBdot Thanks! These are the paths I've used in my own environment, but if you have any specific suggestions for an edit, I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: @Leonardo its just that your paths don't look right to me when I compare it with:`$ ln -s <SOURCE> <LINK_NAME>`. They should be like `$ ln -s /path/to/dir /path/to/symlink` however take for example: ```13 Create a symbolic link to point ~/Microsoft to ~/.microsoft as follows: ln -s ~/Microsoft ~/.microsoft``` Here the symlink is supposed to be ~/Microsoft and not ~/.microsoft as the latter is an actual hidden folder. Does that make sense? I think it should be ln -s ~/.microsoft ~/Microsoft. I dont want to change unless you're convinced.

Comment: @BRBdot you're absolutely right! My apologies for overlooking this - I was extremely tired when I wrote this answer. I've edited it accordingly and credited you for noticing it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LeonardoBraga Thank you for putting together an elaborate answer. :)

Comment: @LeonardoBraga tnx for your help ! I have asp.net core project i create on window and try to run on mac. I try all this levels but still get the same error when i run the docker! what i do wrong? 
1.the password and the path need to be inside brackets right(in secrets.json)?
2.the .env file is just a simple text file with the extension of .env right?
3. we need to do all this levels for any new project ?

Comment: What a nice answer, thanks for sharing your experience 

Comment: Our developer has used VS for windows, however I'm trying to run it via docker-compose on my mac without installing dotnet, is that possible?

Comment: It's saying "Could not find a part of the path '/root/.aspnet/https/<filename>.pfx', even though that file is there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Leonardo Braga, this issue happens when you open, in Visual Studio for Mac, a project that was created using Visual Studio for Windows

I have used the following steps to solve this problem on Visual Studio Mac:

1. Take the backup of the docker files and docker compose project, so to be in the safe side.
2. Delete the docker files and the docker compose project from the solution and respective projects.
3. Re-generate the docker files and docker compose by right click on the project and Add -> Add Docker Support

This is to me the easiest way to resolve the above issue.

Comment: tnx, but then what? when you push you just 'ignore' this files again ?

Comment: I found that the culprit (for me) was actually the `volumes` entry the `docker-compose.override.yml` file. You just need to replace "${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/" with "~/.aspnet/" and "${APPDATA}/Microsoft/" with "~/.microsoft/"

Comment: The solution given by @Brett was a winner for me. Should be a post reply to have more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

As @Raj mentioned, the issue occurs when you open a project on a Mac where the project was originally created on windows.  The root cause is that the docker-compose.override.yml file auto generated by Visual Studio uses windows paths.

You could either delete and re-add container orchestration to the solution (which would presumably create the ‘Docker-compose.override.yml’ file correctly) or simply search the compose files for windows paths and replace with unix equivalent. For example, in the volumes section, replace "${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/" with "~/.aspnet/" and "${APPDATA}/Microsoft/" with "~/.microsoft/"